# How can a procedural macro check a generic type for Option<Option<T>> and flatten it down to a single Option?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I'm writing a derive procedural macro where all of the values are converted to `Options`.  The problem is that any `Option` fields in the struct can be contained within these `Option` types. On its own, this isn't much of an issue until I start to serialize the data with serde.  I want to be able to skip any values where the value is `None`, but there are cases where it will come out to being something like `Some(None)` or `Some(CustomOption::None)`.  Both of these cases are not any more meaningful than a simple `None`, but I can't just write `#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]` on the derived fields.  Of course, they output a `null` value in a JSON format though.

Basically, I want to be able to use the syn library to check to see if the type of a derived field's inner value is going to be an `Option` and flatten it out into a singular `Option<T>` in the derived struct instead of an `Option<Option<T>>` type.  I wish Rust had type-based pattern matching on the generics but that's not really a thing.

I can think of two solutions to this problem but I can't really think of how to implement them.  First one would be to traverse all of the fields and find the `Option`s, then unwrap those options and re-wrap them so that they only have a single `Option` on the outside.  One potential problem with this solution is that I may have to rewrap them in another `Option` after doing the computations. The second solution would be to find the `Option` and modify the generated code accordingly so that if the inner option contains `None` the entire thing becomes `None`; basically just have a helper function that outputs a boolean if the field is an `Option`. Any ideas on how to implement either of these or a better solution?

Here's a code example:

```rust
#[derive(Macro)]
struct X {
    a: usize,
    b: SomeType<String>,
    c: Option<String>,
}
```

```rust
struct GeneratedX {
    a: Option<usize>,
    b: Option<SomeType<String>>,
    c: Option<Option<String>>,
}
```

Using a function like this to wrap all of the values in Options:

```rust
pub fn wrap_typ_in_options(&self) -> TokenStream {
    // self is a struct with the type Type in it along with some other items.
    let typ: syn::Type = self.typ();

    // attribute to check if should ignore a field.
    if self.should_ignore() {
        quote! { Option<#typ> }
    } else {
        quote! { Option<<#typ as module::Trait>::Type> }
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that you can only look at tokens. A type like `MyFoo` could actually be a type alias for an optional. You'd have no way of detecting that.

Comment: It's actually a little unclear what you are asking. Generating the struct fields without nested Options? Or dealing with the value conversions?

Comment: Not worried about aliases since this library's use is only for a very specific project.  And one of my solutions uses the former and one uses the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a solution for this problem following the second idea that I had in the original post. I used a function like this to tell if the token was an `Option`:

```rust
let idents_of_path = path
    .segments
    .iter()
    .fold(String::new(), |mut acc, v| {
        acc.push_str(&v.ident.to_string());
        acc.push(':');
        acc
    });
vec!["Option:", "std:option:Option:", "core:option:Option:"]
    .into_iter()
    .find(|s| idents_of_path == *s)
    .and_then(|_| path.segments.last())
```

I then added a new method called `is_option` which returns a boolean if the `Type::Path` was an option.

```rust
pub fn is_option(&self) -> bool {
    let typ = self.typ();

    let opt = match typ {
        Type::Path(typepath) if typepath.qself.is_none() => Some(typepath.path.clone()),
        _ => None,
    };

    if let Some(o) = opt {
        check_for_option(&o).is_some()
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

I modified the generated code based on the results of this call in a way that is similar to how I am handling my various attributes. All of this should work fine for my specific use-case since no aliased `Option` will ever be introduced into this ecosystem. Its a little messy but it gets the job done for now.