# How do I get the inner type of an Option field in a procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to figure out what the inner type is in an Option type. I'm creating a derive macro called `Builder`

Say I have this struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, Builder)]
pub struct Test {
    foo: Option<String>,
}
```

Then I want to refer to the `String` part. I figured out how to check if it's an Option by reading this question: [How can a procedural macro check a generic type for Option<Option<T>> and flatten it down to a single Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878327/how-can-a-procedural-macro-check-a-generic-type-for-optionoptiont-and-flatte)

But I can only see that the type is an Option, not what its generics are. How do I find them? It must be stored somewhere

This is a small portion of what I have:

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder)]
pub fn derive_builder(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    let ast = syn::parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    impl_builder(&ast).into()
}

fn impl_builder(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> TokenStream {
    let fields = get_fields(&ast.data);
    let setters = fields.named.iter().map(|field| {
        let name = field.ident.as_ref().unwrap();
        let ty = &field.ty;
        if is_option(&ty) {
            // ----------------------------------------------------------
            // | I want to know what the inner type of Test.foo is here |
            // | What to do here to get String?                         |
            // ----------------------------------------------------------
        } else {
            // Default behaviour
            let function_signature = quote!(pub fn #name (self, input: #ty) -> Self);
            quote!(
                #function_signature {
                    let mut data = self.data;
                    data.#name = input;
                    Self {
                        data
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    });

    quote!{
        #(#setters)*
    }
}

fn get_fields(data: &Data) -> FieldsNamed {
    if let Data::Struct(strct) = data {
        if let Fields::Named(fields) = &strct.fields {
            fields.to_owned()
        } else {
            panic!("Can only handle named fields")
        }
    } else {
        panic!("Can only handle structs");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is _very_ unreliable. It will not detect `Option` in several cases (for example, when it is type-aliased) and will mis-detect it in other cases. Consider using a type level approach instead, if you can.

Comment: Nitpick: you use `to_owned()` when you should use `clone()`. `to_owned()` also works (everywhere `clone()` works), but it's unidiomatic.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman >"Consider using a type level approach instead, if you can."

I would love to, but how do I do that?

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The first objective is to split the fields in the provided structs into two groups, the ones that have type `Option<T>` and the ones that have `T`. For each field I need to know `T` (not its path but I want to be able to use it in `quote!`).

Comment: Within the macro, you cannot split the types into two groups, because types aren't decided yet. But what are you planning to do with those groups?

Comment: The end goal is a bit more complicated, but I'm trying to create a typestate builder that only has a build function available if all mandatory fields are set (These mandatory fields might include a specific combination of `Option<T>` fields. Maybe at least one in a user defined group. This part could be defined by attributes)

Comment: Have you tried throwing `ty` into `dbg!` and see what the compiler prints? That might give you some [hint](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0259acaf90f0c582b6f16bd7bab7fde7)s. (Please take this wall of comments to chat...)

Comment: Now _that_ feels like something achievable. To give you a rough idea of how this might work: specialization feels like a good fit for that. However, specialization is unstable. But we have [autoref (or autoderef) specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/tree/master/autoref-specialization), and this is a perfect fit for it. Try to advance with that. If you get stuck, feel free to ask here!

Comment: Well, or have a look at a crate that [already implements](https://docs.rs/typed-builder-macro/latest/src/typed_builder_macro/field_info.rs.html#53-76) this functionality.

Comment: But also, if you're developing a crate for the public, consider that not always `Option` signals that this field is optional. Sometimes we have `Option` yet we want to require this field. Sometimes we don't have an `Option` but the field is optional (and we want to provide some default value for it, commonly `Default::default()`). So, at least consider adding a way to opt-out for your magic and opt-in for manual registration.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I can get it to work now. For some reason I got complaints that `ty` didn't implement debug, but with @Caesar examples I can see where I need to look. Thanks a lot you both!

Answer (score 3):

A little(?)  juggling and you get it:

```rust
fn option_type(ty: &syn::Type) -> Option<&syn::Type> {
    let syn::Type::Path(ty) = ty else { return None };
    if ty.qself.is_some() {
        return None;
    }

    let ty = &ty.path;

    if ty.segments.is_empty() || ty.segments.last().unwrap().ident.to_string() != "Option" {
        return None;
    }

    if !(ty.segments.len() == 1
        || (ty.segments.len() == 3
            && ["core", "std"].contains(&ty.segments[0].ident.to_string().as_str())
            && ty.segments[1].ident.to_string() == "option"))
    {
        return None;
    }

    let last_segment = ty.segments.last().unwrap();
    let syn::PathArguments::AngleBracketed(generics) = &last_segment.arguments else {
        return None;
    };
    if generics.args.len() != 1 {
        return None;
    }
    let syn::GenericArgument::Type(inner_type) = &generics.args[0] else {
        return None;
    };

    Some(inner_type)
}
```