# Good way to extract inner type if type is Option<_> in Rust producedural macros?

Tags: rust, macros

I want to build a function for Rust procedural macros that takes a type and does the following:

- If `Option<_>`, return the inner type along with `true`
- Otherwise, return the type along with `false`

I came up with the following:

```rust
fn optioned_type(ty: &syn::Type) -> (&syn::Type, bool) {
    if let syn::Type::Path(syn::TypePath {
        path: syn::Path { ref segments, .. },
        ..
    }) = ty
    {
        if segments.len() == 1 && segments[0].ident == "Option" {
            if let syn::PathSegment {
                arguments:
                    syn::PathArguments::AngleBracketed(syn::AngleBracketedGenericArguments {
                        ref args,
                        ..
                    }),
                ..
            } = segments[0]
            {
                if args.len() == 1 {
                    if let syn::GenericArgument::Type(ref inner_ty) = args[0] {
                        println!("inner type {:?}", inner_ty);
                        (inner_ty, true)
                    } else {
                        (ty, false)
                    }
                } else {
                    (ty, false)
                }
            } else {
                (ty, false)
            }
        } else {
            (ty, false)
        }
    } else {
        (ty, false)
    }
}
```

The idea is for this to be used in a derive macro on structs where it will inspect the fields of the struct. Fields that are `Option<_>` will be optional and fields without `Option` will be required.

I arrived at this by following the types. It's rather obtuse. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you expect the proc macro to be used? Please give examples.

Comment: @PitaJ I've amended, but basically a derived macro on structs where `Option` will denote optional fields. The function is intended to identify if a type is `Option<_>`.

Comment: `let ... else` can avoid the nesting, and see [my answer to basically the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77040924/7884305), but better to do this with the type system.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Wow, looks like we did essentially the same thing. What do you mean "better to do this with the type system"? How?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but the general idea is to generate some type magic (the same for all types) that will dispatch at compile-time to the correct situation (optional/not).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman A good analogy is command line parsing (e.g. with clap). If the field is `Option<_>`, the parameter is optional, otherwise not. Trying to do a similar thing. But because the `struct` fields need to be looked at by the proc macro to see if a field is optional or not, and it's really just data and not in the type system yet when the proc macro runs, I don't know how to achieve it with the type system. It would clearly be the preferred way if possible. Saves having the final code need to see if the path is `Option`, or `std::option::Option`, or `core::option::Option`, etc ...

Comment: If this is really like command line parsing, then it is only needed to be known if it is optional at runtime. So this is the easiest case - just use specialization and pass a bool. Specialization is unstable, but we have [autoref (or autoderef)](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/tree/master/autoref-specialization) specialization.

Comment: One issue with going this route is that `Option` isn't guaranteed to mean `::std::option::Option` and users may be caught unawares if they encounter this edge case.

Comment: Or even the other way around: if you alias `Option` (which happens very often for `Result`, for instance) you won't detect it with a macro.